# Force refresh REACTjs application the same way as ctrl+F5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple question. I have a REACTjs application which does some requests to the API when starting. These requests are usually done only once but once in a while, user might want to refresh the application manually.

When performing ctrl+F5 (or refresh the page via browser), it works fine.

I tried adding a button with the same functionality like this to my application:

```
<button value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload(true)">Refresh</button>
```

but it only performs two requests: `0.junk.js` and `0.junk.js.map` which both returns 304 status.

Is there a way how to achieve the same behavior as refreshing with browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a string like that is a valid prop you can pass to an `onClick`. That looks like the way you would do it using plain old html. You would have to pass a function to `onClick` like `<button value="Refresh Page" onClick={() => window.location.reload(true)}>`

Answer (score 5):

Try calling a function:

```
onClick={() => window.location.reload(true)}
```

Or Simply update any state of your main component:

```
this.setState({ refresh: true })
```